# How to echo <img src with PHP variables as values of the src attribute

Tags: php, image, variables, attributes, echo

I am getting error when I try to echo image in PHP.  Here is my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, title, filename FROM images";
$result = $conn->query($sql);


if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pathx = "directory/images/";

    echo '
    <img src = "'$pathx'.'$row["filename"]'">
    ';
    //filenames in database end with appropriate image extensions like .png

}
```

And I am getting this error: 
    **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$pathx' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' 
    or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\display.php on line 29**

I have checked solutions from similar questions from here on Stackoverflow and implemented some of the accepted answers still my problem is not solved.

meanwhile something like the code below works well. So why is the one above not working?

```
echo'<img src = "directory/images/girl-g2109_5_720.jpg">';
```

Comment: `$pathx = "directory/images/";
$file = $row["filename"];

echo '<img src = "'.$pathx.$file.'">';`

Comment: `echo '<img src = "'.$pathx.$row["filename"].'">';`

Comment: Perfect @Abdulla, you got my problem solved. Thanks

Comment: My question has been marked duplicate. The answer supposed to be the original is quite an advanced answer that will be helpful to beginners only if they are specifically told what is wrong with their code. The original answer made sense to me because I first got the answer from this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this

```
$pathx = "directory/images/";
$file = $row["filename"];

echo '<img src="'.$pathx.$file.'">';
```

---

**Output**

```
<img src="directory/images/girl-g2109_5_720.jpg">
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pathx = "directory/images/";
    echo '<img src = "'.$pathx.$row["filename"].'">';
}
```

OR use can also use following way to render img tag

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $pathx = "directory/images/"; ?> 
    <img src = "<?php echo $pathx.$row["filename"] ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is an issue with the array concatenation.

The string `'<img src = "'` and variable `$pathx` are not concatenated properly.

There should be a concatenation operator ('.') in between.

Change the code to the following format to fix the issue.

**Code**

```
echo '<img src = "' . $pathx . $row["filename"] . '">';
```

**Output**

```
<img src="directory/images/girl-g2109_5_720.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this**

There are multiple ways to display the image. You can also use like this.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $image=$row["filename"];
?>
<img src="directory/images/<?php echo $image;?>">
<?php
}
 ?>
```

**Output**

```
<img src="directory/images/image_name.png">
```